# Laravel: Dynamically retrieve nested resource from one controller

Tags: laravel, url, resources, nested

## Case

I have two objects, `User` and `Item` (for now but could be more later on) on which I can attach files using the following urls patterns :

```
/users/:user_id/attachments/:id
/items/:item_id/attachments/:id
```

In order to keep being DRY, I want to use only one unique controller (`AttachmentsController`) to handle every case.

## The problem

Using a unique controller, nested resource could be either a `User` or an `Item` (or any other object that I would like to attach to it). Is there a way, using `Route` or `Request` to retrieve dynamically those resources (User, Item...etc...) from this controller ?

**Ideal context**

The ideal use case for me would be to be able to retrieve url pattern such as `/users/:user_id/attachments/:id` so I can dynamically lookup the object to use (see the Rails solution below). Of course if a better way around it exist, I'm in.

I was also thinking doing something like a mixin that would retrieve dynamically that object :

```
trait ResourceFinder
{
    public function behaveableFrom(Request $request, $id)
    {
        $patternWords = explode('/', $request->path());
        $classname = ucfirst(str_singular($words[0]));
        return $classname::findOrFail($id);
    }
}
```

**Equivalent Rails solution**

For information, I covered the exact same case on Ruby on Rails using the following snippet:

```
module Behaveable
  module ResourceFinder
    def behaveable
      klass, param = behaveable_class
      klass.find(params[param.to_sym]) if klass
    end
  end

  def behaveable_class
    params.each do |name, _value|
      if name =~ /(.+)_id$/
        model = name.match(%r{([^\/.]*)_id$})
        return model[1].classify.constantize, name
      end
    end
    nil
  end
end
```

suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found a pretty clean solution using a mixin as I state on my original post.

**routes.php**

```
foreach (['users', 'menus'] as $resource) {
    Route::resource("$resource.attachments", 'AttachmentsController', ['except' => ['create', 'edit']]);
}
```

**App\Http\Controllers\Traits\BehaveableFinder.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Traits;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

trait BehaveableFinder
{
    /**
     * Get the behaveable object.
     *
     * @param  Request  $request
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model
     */
    public function behaveableFrom(Request $request, $behaveableId)
    {
        $context = explode('/', $request->path())[0];
        $class = 'App\\Models\\' . ucfirst(str_singular($context));
        return $class::findOrFail($behaveableId);
    }
}
```

**App\Http\Controllers\AttachmentsController.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Http\Controllers\Traits\BehaveableFinder;

class AttachmentsController extends Controller
{
    use BehaveableFinder;

    /**
     * Get attachable's medias.
     *
     * GET http://domain.com/:attachable/:attachableId/attachments
     *
     * @param  Request  $request
     * @param  int      $attachableId
     * @return Response
     */
    public function index(Request $request, $attachableId)
    {
        $attachable = $this->behaveableFrom($request, $attachableId);
        return response()->json($attachable->medias, 200);
    }

    // ...rest of crud methods works the same way
}
```

The advantage here is that this `mixin` can then be used in any other polymorphic context such as comment (commentable object) for example. The limitation with this approach is that it only work on nested level with a depth of 2. However, it's generally a good practice to avoid too much level of nesting on your REST design.

As I think there is always room for improvement, I would love to see other approach on this if you have any, so suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

You can use route recource controller.

```
Route::resource('user.attachments', 'AttachmentsController');
```

http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/controllers#restful-nested-resources
But there you want to use one controller, so you have such options:
1) Create some checker for each method in restful controller to check if this is `Item` or `User`
2) Create some AttachmentsBaseController with needed methods, and then create
2 others controllers User\ItemController which will extend base Controller. In this way you can define base workflow, and if something will change depends on User\Item you can redefine needed methods in related controller.

Comment: I have updated my post with an example of what I started to do. A bit hackish but does the job. Instead of inheritance here, I would maybe rely more on mixin to add extra functionnality in order to get the correct class to use (your point 1)

Comment: If you use only 1 method or 2, this maybe be better, but if use all methods needed for crud, there will be a lot of mess code.

Comment: Yeah, that's why I want to use a mixin which will for example give an extra method `getBehaveable($request, $behaveableId)` that will return the right object instance. Will try to come with a proper solution and post it here. If you have any other suggestion/example, would love to see it :) I have updated my post

Comment: Sorrym but for now no any new idea :)